# Why I can't do a let with decimals in a shell? What is a BC?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I'm trying to do this in Ubuntu virtualbox with a shell text:

```
#!/bin/bash

n1=3.5
n2=3.6
n3=3.7
n=3
let promedio=n1+n2+n3/3
echo $promedio
```

is about the Average student grade. But then the terminal shows the error:

```
line 7: let: 3.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")
```

Why? I can't do the + with numbers. What can I do?

I was reading about BC command but I don't know where it goes.

EDIT: I tried adding | BC at the end but is the same error. Also I tried looking at a post about this but they use something different I really don't understand because I'm really new with Ubuntu. They use the `$echo` or something like that but the code I'm using is different.

Comment: @Melebius VTC + Please upvote the bc answer to the linked duplicate question that you found useful. I upvoted [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/379243/) because I thought it was more useful than the other one.

Comment: @karel I guess OP wants to use the calculation in a shell script, so I find the `echo | bc` form better. It’s covered by the most upvoted [steeldriver’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/378667/250300). But you are right… I’ve upvoted it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no floating point arithmetic operation in bash. So, you can use BC to calculate it:

```
#!/bin/bash

n1=3.5
n2=3.6
n3=3.7
promedio=`echo $n1 + $n2+ $n3/3 | bc`
echo $promedio   # 3.5 + 3.6 + 1 = 8.1 **This might be not what you want**
```

BC is a simple command line calculator.

BTW, `echo <expression> | bc` command will send the calculation of the expression that is obtained using BC to bash.

A little explanation:

- So, by encapsulating with two **`**, you are telling that the value
  promedio is a result that is obtained by command. (In other words, it
  is called command substitution, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440088/what-is-command-substitution-in-a-shell) for more information)
- By using `echo` you are saying that the result will be the output
  of some calculation that is obtained by BC.
- And there is a logical flaw in these commands, if you use `bc` like
  this, it will divide in terms of integer, (3.7/3 = 1), so you should
  use `bc -l` command to (3.7/3 = 1.2333...) calculate precisely.

And to divide the sum of these 3 numbers, you should properly do parenthesis:

```
#!/bin/bash

n1=3.5
n2=3.6
n3=3.7
promedio=`echo "($n1 + $n2+ $n3)/3" | bc -l`
echo $promedio     # (3.5 + 3.6 + 3.7)/3 = 3.60000...
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Hey mind if I ask you, what does the " ` " little dot means in the bc and echo? I'm trying to learn all about this. Thanks

Comment: I think the expression is meant to be: `($n1 + $n2 + $n3) / 3`

Comment: @LeoTwix, I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Olimjon Okay, I will check.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I tried that but it shows the error "command substitution: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `$n1'
./estudiante.sh: command substitution: line 7: `echo ($n1 + $n2 + $n3) / 3 | bc' "

Comment: By the way, `$( )` should be [preferred for command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/what-is-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming).

Comment: @Olimjon Thank you very much for explaining it. I learned a lot from that right now. That's why it said 8.1 and the calculator shows 3.6. Thanks again and to the other people too for helping me.

Comment: @LeoTwix, you are welcome)