# Alias for BASH integer calculator

Tags: bash, alias

My .bash_aliases file is populated with single-letter aliases (such as o for `octave-cli` and r for `sudo reboot`.

For a while I've been wanting to implement BASH's built-in calculator to do quick calculations, mostly integer multiplication and exponentiation. Sometimes I'll run `echo $((expression))` in the terminal, however it would be great to make a shorthand for that, so that I could simply write

```bsh
c expression
```

into a terminal. It would be ideal to declaire something like

```bsh
alias c="echo $(($@))"
```

into the .bash_aliases file, however that does not work (it prints a 0 as well as the unsolved expression). In what ways do I have to modify the command above to make it possible for 'expression' `c expression` to be passed onto `echo $(($@))`. I've had the idea of including a function in the .bash_aliases file, however do not know how to correctly direct the argument.

Comment: [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/72456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases cannot take positional parameters. For that you'd need a function:

```
$ c(){ echo "$(($@))";  }
$ c 2+2
4
```

This is not anything new nor dodges the question about aliases. Same has been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter) , [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias), and dozen other posts.

While it is possible to "simulate" the behavior for aliases in some cases with `xargs`, the approach is error prone, difficult to maintain, and doesn't work consistently. In general, if you don't want to use a function for some reason but want to have a command-line utility to perform calculations, use suggestions given in [Any command line calculator for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/378661/295286). A dedicated tool such as those suggested can do more than just bash arithmetic expansion, which is another benefit.